# Hive ORC table empty string

Tags: string, hive, null, hiveql, orc

I have a Hive table whit data stored as ORC.
I write in some fields empty values (blank, '"") but sometimes when I run a select query on this table the empty string columns are shown as NULL in the query result. 
I would like to see the empty values I entered, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see, empty values for NULL in hive table, then you can use NVL function, which can help you to produce default values for NULL column values.

Below is syntax,

```
NVL(arg1, arg2) - here argument 1 is expression or column and arg2 is default value for
                  NULL values.
e.g. Query - SELECT NVL(blank,'') as blank_1 AS FROM db.table;
```

Comment: Hi Ajay. i know that with nvl being read it is possible to translate null values ​​to blank, but i wanted to understand why the tables in ORC format cause this problem and if it can be solved with some table properties.

Comment: from above question, you don't see empty values instead of NULL. How it matters underline hive is keeping it NULL or empty string? in both case there no storage cost. It really matters how user want to see it.